# Android: FirebaseMessaging.getToken() on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I'm having problems using onesignal. I tried to use onesignal on another project and it worked but on this project i get error. I guess some libraries are causing this problem.

**App Gradle**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ersincoskun.focusapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8' }
}       
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation files('libs\\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
def nav_version = "2.3.4"

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

implementation 'com.github.AppIntro:AppIntro:6.1.0'

implementation 'com.akexorcist:round-corner-progress-bar:2.1.1'

implementation 'it.xabaras.android:recyclerview-swipedecorator:1.2.3'

def room_version = "2.3.0"

implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2'

def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"

// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.1'
// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
//retrofit
def retrofitVersion = '2.9.0'
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"

implementation 'me.tankery.lib:circularSeekBar:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:3.0.3'

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:2.4.0-alpha01"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"

implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.22'

implementation 'com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.6'

implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'

implementation 'com.github.MdFarhanRaja:SearchableSpinner:2.0'

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'

implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid"}
```

**Top Level Gradle**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9'
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'

    def nav_version = "2.3.4"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } 
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.ersincoskun.focusapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplicationClass"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Focused Pupa"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.FocusApp"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:node="replace">
    <activity
        android:name="com.ersincoskun.focusapp.view.fragments.watchvideo.FullScreenVideoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">

    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.ersincoskun.focusapp.service.SessionService" />

    <activity android:name="com.ersincoskun.focusapp.view.activities.NotificationActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.ersincoskun.focusapp.view.activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.ersincoskun.focusapp.view.activities.RegisterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

    <activity android:name="com.ersincoskun.focusapp.view.activities.IntroActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.ersincoskun.focusapp.view.activities.SplashScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_path" />
    </provider>

</application>
```

**Application Class**

```
import android.app.Application
import com.onesignal.OneSignal
import androidx.work.Configuration

class MyApplicationClass : Application(),Configuration.Provider {
private val ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    // Enable verbose OneSignal logging to debug issues if needed.
    OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE)

    // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.initWithContext(this)
    OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID)
}

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
    Configuration.Builder()
        .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
        .build()
}
```

**Stacktrace**

i get these errors what should i do to resolve please help me

[my stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzVXs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try initialializing FirebaseApp in your application class to fix this issue.

Application Class

```
import android.app.Application
import com.onesignal.OneSignal
import androidx.work.Configuration

class MyApplicationClass : Application(),Configuration.Provider {
private val ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    // Add this line
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)

    // Enable verbose OneSignal logging to debug issues if needed.
    OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE)

    // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.initWithContext(this)
    OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID)
}

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
    Configuration.Builder()
        .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
        .build()
}
```

Hope this helped you out. Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work , i'm still getting same error